# Retrieve/download data and graphs from webpages on weekly basis

Tags: html, excel, vba, pdf, automation

I'm trying to create a dashboard in Excel, using vba, to automatically retrieve/download data and graphs from web-page. These graphs and data are getting updated every day or weekly. So I want the dashboard to be updated weekly.
One example would be this graph: http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=PLOT_ESI.pdf

I have found some examples online, but could not find any example for a graph in pdf format. Any recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Get_Web_PDF()
 Dim request As Object
 Dim response As String
 Dim html As New HTMLDocument
 Dim website As String
 Dim graph As Variant

website = "http://cdec.water.ca.gov/reportapp/javareports?name=PLOT_ESI.pdf"
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "GET", website, False
request.setRequestHeader " If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response
graph = html.getElementsByClassName("html/body/div[2]/embed").Item(0).innerText
End Sub
```